# Update mysql row determined by a php string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello everyone the problem I am having is that I am unable to update a mysql row with php that is determined by a string. The code that does not work is below

```
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET  $GameName = '5'
WHERE Username='$UserInfo[0]'");
```

But this code works see how the row I want to set changes

```
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET  rowname = '5'
WHERE Username='$UserInfo[0]'");
```

I have already tried to put single quotes around $Gamename to no avail. and cant place the row name in quotes for unknown reasons.
UPDATE:
I have tried to get an error log but the debugger is not recognizing any  problems so to try and help I will post another example that does not work but will help to determine that $UserInfo[0] is not the problem.

```
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET  $GameName = '5'
WHERE Username='beta'");
```

Also To rule out things like the variable `$GameName` from being the problem I tested the code below to no avail.

```
$Column="Addition";
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET   $Column= '5'
WHERE Username='beta'");
```

But the code below this does work

```
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET   Addition= '5'
WHERE Username='beta'");
```

Comment: Can you post the Php error.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do some learning on MySQLi. The way your using it is improper. You should be utilizing prepared statements. By the looks of how you have the first query, you should not have to specify a column name as a variable, but maybe that's where your problem is?

It should be something like below, but as I said before, you should not be specifying the column name using a variable.

```
if ($stmt = $con1->prepare("UPDATE Complete SET ".$GameName." = '5' WHERE Username=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $UserInfo[0]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Why should I not specify a column value as a variable I have a table with one row per page then use a variable to select which row I want to modify and what do prepared statements have to offer.

Comment: You should be specifying the column value as a variable, not the column name as a variable. However, it is a general rule and some rules are meant to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is with quoting. So you can try some of this ways of escaping:

```
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET  `".$GameName."` = '5' WHERE Username='".$UserInfo[0]."'");
```

OR

```
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET  `{$GameName}` = '5' WHERE Username='{$UserInfo[0]}'");
```

By the way, your code is very vulnerable to sql injection.

See [HOW TO PREVENT SQL INJECTION IN PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think the problem is with $GameName... You can try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE Complete SET  ".$GameName." = '5'
WHERE Username='".$UserInfo[0]."'";

mysqli_query($con1, $sql);
```

I think the problem is with $UserInfo[0].

Comment: even like this it still does not work  $GameName="rowname";
 $Username="admin";
$con1=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","admin","db");
$sql = "UPDATE Complete SET  ".$GameName." = '5'
WHERE Username='".$Username."'";

Comment: It will be great if you can give us the Error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `echo` the result `SQL` and run the query to your actual `database GUI` (use `navicat` or something). I think your `$GameName` value could not be a valid column from your database. Since you are using **dynamic** column name, you should consider validating your columns like this:

```
$array_columns = array('column_1', 'column_2', 'name', 'other_col');
if (in_array($GameName, $array_columns)) {
    mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE Complete SET $GameName = '5'
        WHERE Username='$UserInfo[0]'");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that solved my problem the problem was that i need to create my statement before trying to process it and one of my tables columns(The one i was trying to edit) would not edit so I had to remove it then recreate it.

```
$Query="UPDATE Complete SET  " .$UserInfo[9] . "='1' WHERE Username='" . $UserInfo[0] . "'";
mysqli_query($con1,"$Query");
```